# Please help with this combinatorial problem.

Tags: combinatorics

The size of a finite set X is the number of members of X. We say a set of integers $X $of size $n ≥ 1$ is good if and only if it does not contain a nonempty subset $Y$, the sum of whose members is divisible by $n$. Is there a good set of integers of size at least $1$? If so, give an example of a good set of minimal size. Explain your answer. (The sum of the members of a set X = {k} of size 1 is k.)

I have no idea how to approach this problem. I really need an explanation of the thought process on solving this problem in a step by step kind of manner. Thank you.

Comment: Note:  I did not downvote this question, but I suspect that those who did, did so because of the lack of effort shown.  To start on the problem you should try small $n$  $n=1$ is trivial, $n=2$ isn't much harder.  $n=3$ is the first case of real interest.  I have posted a general solution below, but that should not stop you from studying special cases on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not.  To see this, suppose you had such a set $X$ and list the members as $\{x_1,\cdots, x_n\}$.  For $m\in \{1,\cdots, n\}$ we define $s_m=\sum_{i=1}^m x_i$.

There are two possibilities.

I.  No two of the $s_i$ are congruent $\pmod n$.  In this case we are done, because there are $n$ of the $s_i$ and $n$ residue classes so we must have hit all the residue classes, so in particular we must have hit the class $0$.

II.  We can find $1≤a<b≤n$ with $s_a\equiv s_b\pmod n$.  In this case we are done since $$s_b-s_a=\sum_{i=a+1}^bx_i\equiv 0 \pmod n$$

Perhaps a concrete example would clarify matters.  Let's take $$X=\{2,3,5,9,10,14\}$$  Then $$\{s_m\}_{m=1}^6=\{2,5,10,19,29,43\}$$  We are only interested in the remainders on division by $6$ so we reduce $\pmod 6$ to get $$\{s_m \pmod 6\}_{m=1}^6=\{2,5,4,1,5,1\}$$  We remark that $s_2\equiv s_5\pmod 6$ and we check that indeed $$s_5-s_2=5+9+10=24$$ is divisible by $6$, as desired.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the post and the comment above. It wasn't a lack of trying. I honestly don't know how to approach problems like this. I'm a philosophy major and this problem is actually from a philosophy class. I don't know why we're doing problems like this. If you don't mind, would it be possible to explain and answer in more layman terms?

Comment: Well, I would suggest trying it for small $n$.  For $n=3$ you really should be able to handle it (hint:  we don't really care what integers, exactly, you choose...we only care about their remainders on division by $3$).  As to my argument...at least it is constructive.  Try working it out explicitly with an actual set $X$.

Comment: Perhaps there is an easier way to see this, but if there is I can not spot it (which, of course, doesn't mean that there isn't one).  That's why I posted the solution instead of just giving hints.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, but let's say in n=3, the integers in set X are {1, 2, 3}. Let's say the subset Y is also {1, 2, 3}. The sum of the integers of Y is divisible by 3 in this case, which means X is not a good set. This is what I've thought of so far. Am I on the right track? But it seems in this is a very specific case, and doesn't work if X happens to have other integers, right? For example, if X was {2, 4, 5}. I don't know how to make it so it applies to all possibilities. Oh actually, that last example works as well if Y = {4, 5}, but I think you get what I was saying.

Comment: As I suggested, just look at the remainders on division by $3$.  Your first example is then the same as $\{1,2,0\}$ so we are immediately done (just take the last element).  Your second set is the same as $\{2,1,2\}$ and we see that the sum of the first two should work.

Comment: The point of working with remainders is that, for each $n$, you just have a finite problem.  there are only three possible remainders on division by $3$, namely $0,1,2$.  Thus, at worse, you only have to look at $27$ cases.  In truth, you only need to look at $8$ cases since if $0$ appears you are immediately finished.

Comment: I have to say, though, if you have absolutely no experience either with combinatorics nor with modular arithmetic, this is kind of a silly problem to be starting with.  Maybe your instructor has a different approach in mind, but to me some sort of abstraction is definitely called for.

Comment: Note:  I have edited my post to include an explicit example of the method for a specific set with $6$ elements.

Comment: Yes, that's what I don't understand about this class. There's no prerequisite for this class, and it's a philosophy class. I honestly don't understand why we're getting problems like this. I've never felt this lost in a class before.

Comment: Well, good luck to you.  If it happens that your instructor has a more elementary way of resolving this question, you might come back and post it here as another solution.  I am skeptical regarding the existence of a dramatically  better argument, but then I am often wrong about things.

Comment: Well, anyways, thank you for very much for the time. I'll try to make sense of what you told me.